# Gnome equivalent of KDirStat

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

What is the Gnome version of [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)? I read some 2006 post about program named Baobab , but it looks like it's not included in 10.04 any more, and the home page is not available any more.

Answer (score 12):

That's odd, `baobab` sits in my `Applications -> Accessories` menu since quite some versions, it's called `Disk Usage Analyzer`.

Comment: and I think natty calls it `filelight`

Comment: @sehe Baobab and Filelight are similar programs, but not the same.